# Proxy through EC2 Instance on lambda functions locally using squid

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, proxy, squid

So I have a lambda function that sends a request to an API through the EC2 IP and everything works fine...
Except when I try to send the request locally while testing it doesn't work as the EC2 IP is the only whitelisted IP and my IP is dynamic so it changes alot

What I thought of doing is adding Squid and proxying through it which works fine if I use ssh to connect to it whether requests sent to http or https but that created another problem not all the developers will have access to that EC2 instance...

So I made it publically available and made basic authentication on it except now it doesn't requests to HTTPS unless its google or certain websites.

My question is that why do requests to HTTPS always not work when connecting to the proxy without the SSH tunnel but if it's on something like google it works instantly cause they have less redirects

Comment: It is not clear to me what is your question or the issue you are facing. Please edit your post to add more details and to give us more information, so we can help you.

Comment: My question is that why do requests to HTTPS always not work when connecting to the proxy without the SSH tunnel but if it's on something like google it works instantly cause they have less redirects @Azize